# Html5 video element play decrypted data from memory

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, electron, html5-video

I am trying to build a desktop application with nodejs and electron that plays encrypted (crypto built-in module), embedded mp4 video files.

Here is my code that writes the decrypted data to a file and plays the data through it.
Could anyone help me so my video player plays the data through memory without writing the data to a file?

```
var key ="12345678asdfghjk"
var keyBuf = new Buffer(key);
var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(file+"c");
var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(file+"d");
var cipher = crypto.createDecipher("aes-128-cbc", keyBuf);

inputStream.on('data', function(data) {
  var buf = new Buffer(cipher.update(data), 'binary');
  outputStream.write(buf);
 });

inputStream.on('end', function() {
  try {
    var buf = new Buffer(cipher.final('binary'), 'binary');
    outputStream.write(buf);
    outputStream.end();
      
    outputStream.on('close', function() {       
    const introVideo=document.getElementById("introVideo");
    introVideo.src = "data:video/mp4;base64,"+fs.readFileSync(file+"d", "base64")
    introVideo.play()
        
    });
    } catch(e) {
     console.log(e)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Not sure, but i think you can do this through "blob" urls or the "file reader" api.

Comment: Thank you Marc for your answer, nice idea, although I solved it in another way.

Comment: Then post your answer and mark it as. This helps other people with the same problem.

Comment: @chris_p what was your solution? please post as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
decrypt(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    const fs = require('fs'); 
    const crypto = require('crypto'); 
    const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer; 
    const pass = new Buffer('"+key+"'); 
    const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(file); 
    const cipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc', pass); 

    var base64encodedData = ''; 

    inputStream.on('data', function(data) { 
      base64encodedData += new Buffer(
        cipher.update(data, 'binary', 'base64'),         
        'binary'
      ); 
    }); 

    inputStream.on('end', function() {
      base64encodedData += new Buffer(cipher.final('base64'), 'binary');
      return resolve(base64encodedData); 
    }); 
  }); 
}
```

I am very sorry for the delayed answer!
@Eric Carmichael if you need any further information let me know!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.